# Custom properties on Custom Elements

Tags: javascript, custom-element

After a custom element has been parsed and added to the DOM, can I get access to a custom property I created at the constructor time, like:

```js
    const props = []
    return new CustomElement(props)

    // later in code

    class CustomElement {
      ...
      constructor(props) {
         this.customProperty = props
      }
      toString() {
         return this.outerHTML
      }
      ...
    }

    // later in code
    const ce = document.querySelector("custom-element")
    console.log( ce.customProperty ) // []
```

Comment: You need to make sure your custom element is properly registered `customElements.define('custom-element', CustomElement);`.

Comment: The purpose of the showing code is to focus on the relevan aspects of the question. Of course I've already define the element. @connexo

Answer (score 0):

Yes, no different than regular DOM elements.

And with `document.createElement("custom-element")` your property is there too.

Note with the latter only the `constructor` was executed.
So props you add in the `connectedCallback` won't be set yet.

For these type of questions try your own code in a JSFiddle or CodePen or https://webcomponents.dev

Comment: have you tried that at least before answering the question? This does not work in any case.